# Rails: Enums with hashes not returning hash key:value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I am building a Ruby on Rails Application where I have model attributes that are static like `Gender` and `Status`. I have decided to define them as `enums` in the models. I am using the [ruby-enum](https://github.com/dblock/ruby-enum) gem to define the enums.

I have added the [ruby-enum](https://github.com/dblock/ruby-enum) gem to my project, and ran `bundle install`:

```
gem 'ruby-enum', '~> 0.8.0'
```

However, the enums needs to be accessible by various other models, so I have defined the enums as **modules** in the **concerns** directory of my models:

```
# app/models/concerns/status.rb

module Status
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    include Ruby::Enum

    define :ordered, 'Ordered'
    define :cancelled, 'Cancelled'
    define :waiting, 'Waiting'
  end
end
```

I have included this module in my `Users` model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Status
end
```

And my `Users` model has a column for `status`:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "first_name"
  t.string "last_name"
  t.string "status"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

But when I query the Status module in the `rails console`:

```
Status.all
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `all' for Status:Module)
```

When I also query the `User` Model in the rails console for all `statuses`:

```
User.statuses.all
```

I get the error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1))
```

I also don't know how to make this available in the views

```
  # app/views/users/_form.html.erb

  <%= form.label :status %><br />
  <%= form.select :status, User.statuses.keys.collect { |status| status },{} %>
```

How can I go about defining the enums and also returning the key values of the enums in the users' form view so that a status can be selected in the form?

Comment: [Rails already has enums](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). Where is `User.statuses` defined?

Comment: The thing is that I want to use the hash method for the enums, in such a way that the key `order` can value the `Order`, which I didn't see in the rails enums, it's uses integers. Also, I did not define `User.statuses` anywhere. I was just trying on how to query the `Users` table to get all the `statuses`.

Comment: What's the point of an enum that maps to a string? What are you trying to accomplish? If it's to store how the status is to be displayed, that's the job of a [decorator](https://github.com/drapergem/draper). Or consider `user.status.humanize` instead. Note that Rails enums are mapped between integers and strings when loaded.

Comment: I want to see the values of the enums like `Order` and not `order` in the views page. I want to see `Not ordered` and not `not_ordered` in the views page. I also want the values of the `status` to be stored in the database and not the integers like `0, 1, 2`.

Comment: I would suggest use built in enum feature of rails and use supportive gems like https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/translate_enum/0.1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when I query the Status module in the rails console:
>
> ```
> Status.all
> ```
>
> I get the error:
>
> ```
> NoMethodError (undefined method `all' for Status:Module)
> ```

`.all` asks for all the records of an ActiveRecord class. `Status` is not an ActiveRecord class. It isn't even a class, it is a module.

As for `User.statuses.all`, I don't see where `statuses` is defined.

---

`Ruby::Enum` has added some constants and methods, but Rails doesn't know about them. You'd have to integrate them into Rails yourself.

[Rails already has enums](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) which are integrated.

```
module Status
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    # It will take an Array, but it's good practice to be explicit.
    enum status: {ordered: 0, cancelled: 1, waiting: 2}
  end
end
```

`User.statuses` will return a [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) of your statuses.

Note that these enums are mapped to integers, strings defeat the point of an enum. Storing your status as an integer will save you potentially a lot of space. Rails will handle mapping the integers into strings and back for you.

Be sure to change your table to use integer status: `t.string "status"`. To avoid Users with on status, you will want to define either a default or a `null: false`.

---

> I want to see Order and not order in the views page. I want to see Not ordered and not not_ordered in the views page. I also want the values of the status to be stored in the database and not the integers like 0, 1, 2. – Promise Preston 12 secs ago

Details of how data is displayed does not belong in the database. Simplest thing is to use [`humanize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize).

```
# ordered becomes Ordered. not_waiting becomes Not waiting.
User.statuses.keys.collect { |status| status.humanize }
```

You can push that off into the Status module.

```
module Status
  ...

  class_methods do
    def show_statuses
      statuses.keys.collect { |status| status.humanize }
    end
  end
end

User.show_statuses
```

Doing this as a select...

```
<%= f.select :status, User.statuses.collect { |status,id| [status.humanize,id] } %>
```

And you can also push that into Status.

```
module Status
  ...

  class_methods do
    ...

    def statuses_for_select
      statuses.collect { |status,id| [status.humanize,id] }
    end
  end
end

<%= f.select :status, User.statuses_for_select %>
```

As your display details become more complicated your models will get fat. Then you'll want to consider pushing it off into a [decorator](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you please include in the answer, a way I can change the display of how the enums are, say `not_ordered` to `Not ordered` using `decorators` or `internationazation`. And moreso, how to do a `form.select` for the `statuses` in the `Users` view. I would appreciate.

Comment: @PromisePreston Done.

Comment: Thank you @schwern. And moreso, how to do a form.select for the statuses in the Users view. I would appreciate.

Comment: I used this for the views `<%= form.select :gender, User.statuses.keys.collect { |status| status.humanize }` , but I get this error `ArgumentError ('Not ordered' is not a valid status)`. Do I need to make any change to my controller params for users?

Comment: And one more question please, now that I am using integers for the enums, when the database is exported, will their column show as 0,1,2,3 or will they show as the values of the enums in strings (which is readable)?

Comment: @PromisePreston That depends on how you export it. If you export it using Rails, strings. If you dump the database directly, integers. If you want both you'll need to use a real enum type for the column in the database. Again, I'd advice dropping the idea that the raw database will be well formatted.